# Google sheets - protect sheet except small range

Tags: exception, google-sheets, spreadsheet-protection

My concern is simple: I want to protect the whole sheet except 1 cell, which is a drop down menu. I want them to be able to change that value but impede the edition of the rest of the sheet.

Basically I need the inverse option of protection. Protect the sheet and unprotect a particular range (in this case 1 cell)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just found it.

Data - Protected sheets and ranges
Select 'Sheet' and will allow to select the exception range

See ya'll